# Replicate / SYNC / Copy thousands of files

Tags: windows, storage-area-network, synchronization, file-replication-services

Windows 32BIT Box (Server OS)
4GB RAM
a 800GB LUN Mapped to the above box as a local drive
Around 700GB of text files (Yes text files and a few thousand word documents) nested in thousands of directories.

I need to move this to a new storage and map another server to it.

What would be the best way to go about it ?

What I did was mapped the existing LUN to our new box and mapped a LUN from the New storage to the new box too, and tried copying (windows copy) but that wasn't good / fast enough considering the downtime.

I am now looking for either a script which will do this or a utility (prefer opensource / free) to move this size of data at a good speed.

2 x 1GB Nics teamed > ether channel 2GBPs

Any suggestions or pointers would be off great help
Thanks !

Comment: why down-vote? - it is a legit / proper question :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about mapping the new LUN to the old server and then use [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) or [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) to copy the files?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response : I tried a sync utility but that just freezes after 60Gb ; I guess as the other host is constantly writing to it - may be that's why. also how would I get rsync to work on my new 64BIT windows BOX ?

Comment: @rihatum, which sync utility did you try?

Comment: allwaysync, goodsync - any ideas or suggestions on this ?

Comment: @SvenW, I mapped the existing LUN to my new box, however I have read that it is not a good idea to map a single lun to two hosts (unless in a cluster - which my servers are not) so I have unmapped it now, even though I was only reading from it.

Whoever have down-voted this question, please understand that not everyone here comes without a research, My question intended towards people who deal with terabytes of text files and may have had to move it around, so was looking forward to those suggestions.